# How do I chain multiple promises while passing and updating an object through each promise with additional API calls?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, airtable

I am new to Javascript and am just getting familiar with promises so forgive my ignorance.

What I'm trying to do is request all the records from an Airtable base and filter them them based on a checkbox called "Email Sent" being unsent. When I have the records filtered there are linked records in 2 fields that I need to do additional requests for to get the values for. All of those values (various data, and recipients as an object) then are plugged into an HTML email template and fired off using AWS-SES. Then the "Email Sent" check box is checked for those records to prevent emails from being sent multiple times. The plan is to have this all running on an interval in AWS Lambda. And as records are added to the base they are automatically emailed to a list.

I am able to get the records, and filter them. I am also comfortable with executing the code within Lambda and using SES. But I have been struggling for days to get the values for the linked records. Both of which are lists of people and 1 of which is a recipient email address.

The numerous things I've tried end up either returning the original record  called in the first step or returns undefined. I'm chaining a lot of promises and I don't think I'm doing it right because it seems they are running out of order. I'm also at the point of trying weird things like using a global array instead of an object that I'm passing down through the promises and updating.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```js
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx'}).base('xxxxxxxxxx');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer")
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
const path = require('path');
var AWS = require("aws-sdk")
var ses = new AWS.SES();
var fs = require('fs');

var mainArray = [];

var readHTMLFile = function(path, callback) {
    fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            callback(err);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, html);
        }
    });
};

function getRecords(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var reqArr = [];

      base('Edit Requests').select({
          // Selecting the first 3 records in Grid view:
          maxRecords: 50,
          view: "Grid view"
      }).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
          // This function (`page`) will get called for each page of records.

          records.forEach(function(record) {
            // console.log("108: ", record._rawJson.id)
            var obj = {}
            // obj = record.fields;
            // obj.id = record._rawJson.id;
            console.log("172", record.fields["Editor Preference"])
            obj = record.fields;
            obj.id = record._rawJson.id;

            if(record.fields["Editor Preference"] != undefined){
              obj["Editor Preference"] = obj["Editor Preference"]
              // obj["Editor Preference"] = getEditorWrap(record.fields["Editor Preference"])
            } else {
              obj["Editor Preference"] = "";
            }

            if(record.fields["Production Manager"] != undefined){
              obj["Production Manager"] = obj["Production Manager"]
            } else {
              obj["Production Manager"] = "";
            }

            mainArray.push(obj)
            // console.log(record.fields["Email"])
              // console.log('Retrieved', record.fields['Requested By']);
        })
          // To fetch the next page of records, call `fetchNextPage`.
          // If there are more records, `page` will get called again.
          // If there are no more records, `done` will get called.
          fetchNextPage();
          // console.log("123", reqArr)
          // resolve(reqArr)
      }, function done(err) {
          if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
          // console.log("123", mainArray)
          resolve(mainArray)
      });
      // resolve(reqArr)
    });
}

function filterRecords(arr){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var filtered = []
    mainArray = [];
    // console.log("245", arr)
    for (i in arr){
      if(arr[i]['Email Sent'] == undefined){
        // console.log("247", arr[i])
        mainArray.push(arr[i])

      };
    }
    console.log("filtered: ", mainArray)
    resolve(mainArray)
  });
}

function setObject(array){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    for (i in array){
      var obj = array[i];

      if(obj.id != undefined){

        base('Editors').find(obj.id, function(err, record) {
            if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
            // console.log("281", record.fields);

        });
      }

    }

    resolve(mainArray)
  });
}

function main1(){

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    getRecords().
      then(function(recordArr){
        filterRecords(mainArray).
          then(function(resultArr){
            setObject(mainArray).
              then(function(mainArray){
              })

          })
      })


  });

}



main1().
  then(function(resultArray){
    console.log(resultArray)
  })
```

Comment: I think this question is similar to what you are trying to do -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108966/how-to-return-data-from-the-done-callback-when-working-with-airtable-js

Comment: Taking another look at your code.  You can also remove your filterRecords function if you instead leverage the "filterByFormula" parameter when you fetch records. It looks like you only want records where the Email Sent field is blank.  So it would be  `base('Edit Requests').select({
          maxRecords: 50,
          view: "Grid view",
          filterByFormula: '{Email Sent}=BLANK()'
      })`

Comment: Thanks. That put me on the right track but I'm still struggling with the stacking of the promises. I have multiple linked records and it's not working quite right.